# Why am I getting "error: expected '}'" in C++ but not in C?

Tags: c++, c, enums, boolean

I'm getting `"error: expected '}'"` where the '^' is pointing when I compile in the following C++ source:

```
typedef enum { false, true } Boolean;
               ^
```

I don't get this error when I compile it as C source.

What it the reason for this? I'm stumped!

Comment: You cannot give the names `false` and `true` to anything in C++. Note that `bool` is already a type in C++ and `false` and `true` are its values.

Comment: Why are you recreating bool with an enum?

Comment: You also have `bool` in C99 (include `<stdbool.h>`).

Comment: I heard that using "bool" and "BOOL" causes a lot of problems, and that I should create an enumerated type to handle boolean cases.

Comment: @user2738698: no, people defining *their own* bools using the same name as what C++ already provides, are what's causing problems

Comment: Oh, I meant as code that develops over time, where variables that were originally thought of to be binary, would suddenly become much more complex, like this: [link](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2012/11/19/Why-you-should-never-use-a-boolean-field-use-an.aspx)

Comment: @user2738698 If there is a chance of more values in future, then surely "true" and "false" are not good now. Even if there are just two such values, use descriptive names, like "started" and "stopped" now, perhaps "starting", "suspended", "stopping" etc in future.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`false` and `true` are C++ keywords, so you can't use them as `enum` identifiers.

In C they are not keywords so your code will work, but if you include `<stdbool.h>` then it will fail to compile because that header defines `false` and `true` as macros.

Note that you probably shouldn't implement a boolean type yourself. C++ already has the `bool` type, and if you are using a C99 compiler, you can include `stdbool.h`. This will give you a `bool` type that has `false` and `true` values, similar to C++.

Comment: Replace "probably don't need to" with "shouldn't"?

Comment: If you `#include <stdbool.h>` it will *definitely* fail to compile; `typedef enum { false, true } Boolean;` would expand to `typedef enum { 0, 1 } Boolean;`

Answer (score 6):

To solve this you need to do:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  typedef bool Boolean;
#else
  typedef enum { false, true } Boolean;
#endif
```

That way, you are not trying to use C++ keywords (`true` and `false`) in an `enum`.

Comment: no, even in C there is a Boolean data type, nowadays. Just including stdbool.h should suffice and then you might use the same typedef as you have for C++. Even better would be to use `bool` from the start.

Comment: To solve this, you should write either C or C++. The need to write code that's both valid C and valid C++ is actually quite rare.

Answer (score 2):

The `true` and `false` are keywords in C++. You cannot use them in enum identifiers.

As it is said in the standard :

> **2.12 Keywords [lex.key]**
>
> The identifiers shown in Table 4 are reserved for use as keywords (that is, they are unconditionally treated as keywords in phase 7) except in an attribute-token.
>
> In table 4:
>
> ```
>  false
>  ...
>  true
> ```

In C, they are not keywords, your code should work but the best should be to include `<stdbool.h>` who already defines `true` and `false` then you don't need to define them by yourself.